# How to display copyright notice on web page (Only parts of it are owned by me)

Tags: copyright

I am working on a web application, and I am not sure how to display the copyright notice. The project itself is forked from another project and uses code from other JavaScript libraries not created by myself. Do I need to include this information in the notice? Or do I just simply do this: "Copyright © 2013 Steven Glick - Licensed under GPLv3"

Or do I not need to worry about a copyright notice at all?

Comment: I was just looking around some more and saw that it is by no means required to display the notice, and the fact that it is a GPLv3 licensed site makes it almost completely pointless to add a copyright notice. The code itself does have notices about copyright so it shouldn't be necessary to put it on the page itself.

Comment: Seems like you've got a pretty good answer for this already. Please copy it into an answer below and accept it when you can.

Comment: I would only add to place a copyright notice on any work you consider your own that you want to protect, and keep other copyright notices intact as required by the GPL or otherwise.

Comment: I was going to post that as an answer, but I needed higher rep to post it before 24 hours. I'll post it when I can though :)

Answer (score 1):

You could also make that copyright notice a hyperlink to a [humans.txt](http://humanstxt.org/) file with more details.

Comment: That is a good idea, If I do chose to add a notice I think that is what I will do.

Answer (score 1):

I was just looking around some more and saw that it is by no means required to display the notice, and the fact that it is a GPLv3 licensed site makes it almost completely pointless to add a copyright notice. The code itself does have notices about copyright so it shouldn't be necessary to put it on the page itself.

It is necessary to leave any other copyright notices in place for parts not owned by me, and if you do not want your work used by others it is a good idea to include the copyright notice as it gives you a stronger claim.